# How to avoid double '\' escape when using serde_json in Rust?

Tags: json, rust, escaping, serde

Is it somehow possible to create a String Value from bytes WITHOUT doubling the backslash character in SERDE?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5411c22ac776154aeb1ff84efb94aab4):

```rust
use serde_json::json;
use serde_json::{Value};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let bytes = [79, 66, 88, 90, 70, 65, 68, 54, 80, 54, 76, 65, 92,
                117, 48, 48, 49, 102, 50, 50, 50, 50, 71, 66, 54, 87,
                65, 65, 85, 52, 54, 87, 87, 86, 92, 117, 48, 48, 49, 102,
                123, 92, 34, 36, 116, 122, 92, 34, 58, 92, 34, 69, 117, 114,
                111, 112, 101, 47, 66, 101, 114, 108, 105, 110, 92, 34, 125];
    let string = str::from_utf8(&bytes).unwrap();
    let json_string = json!(&string);
    let json_string2 = Value::String(string.to_string());
    println!("string: {}",string);
    println!("json 1: {}",json_string);
    println!("json 2: {}",json_string2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a string that already contains escapes. To avoid the backslash itself getting escaped, you can interpret the escapes yourself before passing the string to serde. For example, using the [unescape](https://lib.rs/crates/unescape) crate to interpret escapes, the code would look like this:

```
use serde_json::json;
use std::str;
use unescape::unescape;

fn main() {
    let bytes = [
        79, 66, 88, 90, 70, 65, 68, 54, 80, 54, 76, 65, 92, 117, 48, 48, 49, 102, 50, 50, 50, 50,
        71, 66, 54, 87, 65, 65, 85, 52, 54, 87, 87, 86, 92, 117, 48, 48, 49, 102, 123, 92, 34, 36,
        116, 122, 92, 34, 58, 92, 34, 69, 117, 114, 111, 112, 101, 47, 66, 101, 114, 108, 105, 110,
        92, 34, 125,
    ];
    let string_with_escapes = str::from_utf8(&bytes).unwrap();
    let unescaped_string = unescape(string_with_escapes).unwrap();
    let json_string = json!(&unescaped_string);
    println!("string with escapes: {}", string_with_escapes);
    println!("string without escapes: {}", unescaped_string);
    println!("json: {}", json_string);
}
```

Output (but note that *string without escapes* contains some unprintable chars that are not rendered):

```
string with escapes: OBXZFAD6P6LA\u001f2222GB6WAAU46WWV\u001f{\"$tz\":\"Europe/Berlin\"}
string without escapes: OBXZFAD6P6LA2222GB6WAAU46WWV{"$tz":"Europe/Berlin"}
json: "OBXZFAD6P6LA\u001f2222GB6WAAU46WWV\u001f{\"$tz\":\"Europe/Berlin\"}"
```

If you wish to avoid depending on `unescape` (which hasn't been updated since its inception in 2016), you could even let `serde_json` do the unescaping:

```
fn unescape(s: &str) -> serde_json::Result<String> {
    serde_json::from_str(&format!("\"{}\"", s))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a8c70e80729ff04371ecac82190e793)

Answer (score 1):

The following characters are reserved in JSON and must be properly escaped to be used in strings:

- Backspace is replaced with `\b`
- Form feed is replaced with `\f`
- Newline is replaced with `\n`
- Carriage return is replaced with `\r`
- Tab is replaced with `\t`
- Double quote is replaced with `\"`
- Backslash is replaced with `\\`

The answer is "**No**" because if the backslash is not escaped, serde would produce an invalid JSON

> But how is it possible to build a serde_json::Value::String from a &[u8]

You have to create a regular string first, then escape the reserved characters. Luckily serde has provided us with the [`json!()`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html#variant.String) macro to do the latter:

```rust
use serde_json::json;

fn main() {
    // if it's not a UTF-8 encoded string, then you should use some external crate to do the decoding
    let slice: &[u8] = //some utf-8 encoded slice
    let string = String::from_utf8(slice.to_vec()).unwrap();
    let v = json!("hel\"lo");
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you. What I want to do is to build a JSON Object dynamically. Do you know  how to build a `serde_json::Value::String` from a `&[u8]`? E.g. if I have a &[u8]. How can I insert it into a JSON object dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom [`Formater`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/ser/trait.Formatter.html):

```rust
use serde::ser::Serialize;
use serde_json::ser::{CharEscape, Serializer};
use std::{io, str};

struct NoEscape;

impl serde_json::ser::Formatter for NoEscape {
    fn write_char_escape<W: ?Sized>(
        &mut self,
        writer: &mut W,
        char_escape: CharEscape,
    ) -> io::Result<()>
    where
        W: io::Write,
    {
        use self::CharEscape::*;

        let c = match char_escape {
            Quote => '"',
            ReverseSolidus => '\\',
            Solidus => '/',
            Backspace => 'b',
            FormFeed => 'f',
            LineFeed => 'n',
            CarriageReturn => 'r',
            Tab => 't',
            AsciiControl(_) => todo!(),
        };

        write!(writer, "{}", c)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let raw = [
        79, 66, 88, 90, 70, 65, 68, 54, 80, 54, 76, 65, 92, 117, 48, 48, 49, 102, 50, 50, 50, 50,
        71, 66, 54, 87, 65, 65, 85, 52, 54, 87, 87, 86, 92, 117, 48, 48, 49, 102, 123, 92, 34, 36,
        116, 122, 92, 34, 58, 92, 34, 69, 117, 114, 111, 112, 101, 47, 66, 101, 114, 108, 105, 110,
        92, 34, 125,
    ];
    let foo = str::from_utf8(&raw).unwrap();
    let mut ser = Serializer::with_formatter(Vec::new(), NoEscape {});
    foo.serialize(&mut ser).unwrap();
    let writer = ser.into_inner();
    let result = str::from_utf8(&writer).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(
        result,
        r#""OBXZFAD6P6LA\u001f2222GB6WAAU46WWV\u001f{\"$tz\":\"Europe/Berlin\"}""#
    )
}
```